# *Multiple* Print Specific Div

Tags: html, css

I'll try to explain:

I have numerous div classes, but for the sake of simplicity, let's say I only have 3.

Someone is viewing DIV 1, and I want to give them the option of only printing DIV 1, omitting 2 and 3.

However, on the same page, I would like to give them the option to ONLY PRINT DIV 2. Or only print DIV 3.

I think I get how you can omit certain things from getting printed. But how can you select a section here or there on the same page to be printed with a print link.

Thanks,
Tracy

Comment: do you want to print the selected div and the surroundings or just the little divs content itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to show/hide divs. Read the jQuery tutorial:

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

The code will look this way:

```
<script>
function showDiv(n) {
  $('.divs').hide();
  $('#div_'+n).show();
}
$(document).ready(function() { showDiv(1); });
</script>
<a href='javascript:showDiv(n)'>show div n</a>
<div class='divs' id='div_n'>I'm div n</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of how to show/hide divs, but how do you print specific divs?

Answer (score 0):

There are many related posts on printing div content, this particular question was still open though it was asked in '10.. Following JavaScript function can be used for printing content of a selected Div tag. Hope this helps. Declaimer: I used some of the existing answers, fixed/enhanced code/error(s) to work with (and tested on) IE-8.

```
function printDiv(divName) {
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById(divName);
    var newWin = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', 'width=400, height=400, top=100, left=100', '');
    newWin.document.open();
    newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</body></html>');
    newWin.document.close();
    setTimeout(function () { newWin.close(); }, 10);
}
```

Call printDiv from anywhere in page or from within selected Div. Here is test link:

```
<a href="Javascript:printDiv('divCustomerData')">Print Customer Data</a>

<a href="Javascript:printDiv('divOrderData')">Print Order Data</a>
```

Assign respective IDs to Div that is to be printed:

```
<div id="divCustomerData">Div Contents goes here... </div>
```

The only catch right now is it loses css styles. I'll update response when i get a chance to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Just curious if there would be a way to add to this script and call your CSS page to load in the new window as well? I am finding myself needing an answer today, to my question I asked 71/2 years ago!

Comment: Nevermind, that was easy enough. I just added the missing head tags and added the css tag and linked to it.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jasonday/jquery.printThis

I would give each div an id, and then using the above plugin (i wrote) specify according to div id.

Comment: Yes, a lot of years have passed since I posted this question. I have found myself looking for the same answer today. Just wanted to mention that your url has changed on your site from the above you posted, to: https://github.com/jasonday/printThis