# Multiple print styles in one document for different DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing

I have a content slider on a page and I want to allow site visitors to print the contents of only the slide they click on. I have 7 slides and two of them have a button within the slide that says, "Print Contents".   Each slide content is contained within it's own div.

I've successfully used a print specific style sheet before, but am not sure how to set varying print rules for one document.  Is there some kind of JavaScript or jQuery I can apply? I am a novice with both but am willing to give anything a try.

[Here is a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559777/multiple-print-stylesheets-for-sections-on-one-page) but no answers; [this one is close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172084/multiple-print-specific-div) but I need to maintain CSS styles.

any help is appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Set up a CSS rule for your main elements:

```
@media print {
  div.main-element: display: none;
```

Then add another rule:

```
  div.main-element.print-me: display: block;
```

Now you can add a "print" button to each section of content, and have a handler adjust the classes appropriately:

```
 $('body').on('click', '.main-element button.print', function() {
   $('.main-element').removeClass('print-me');
   $(this).closest('.main-element').addClass('print-me');
   window.print();
 });
```

Comment: I've been coming across lots of different solutions to this problem, and this solution, in my opinion, is the cleanest and simplest. Thanks a lot!